# how to create a function that enqueues an entire structure and not just an integer

Tags: c, linked-list

when compiled i receive these messages

> [error] variable or field 'Enqueue' declared void
>   49  14  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] variable or field 'enqueue' declared void
>
> 49 20  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node')
>
> 49 35  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node')
>
> 49 45  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] expected primary-expression before 'struct'
>
> 50 14  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] variable or field 'dequeue' declared void
>
> 50 20  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node')
>
> 51 14  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] variable or field 'getRear' declared void
>
> 51 20  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node*')
>
> 52 15  C:/weblinky1.cpp    [Error] variable or field 'getFront' declared void
>
> 52 21  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node*')
>
> C:\Users\marshalee\Desktop\DSLabTest1_1300054246\weblinky1.cpp In function 'int main()':
>
> 60 11  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'documents' and 'node*')
>
> 114    49  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'enqueue' was not declared in this scope
>
> 122    39  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'dequeue' was not declared in this scope
>
> 126    27  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'documents' and 'long long int')
>
> 138    42  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'deletedocsize' was not declared in this scope
>
> 147    48  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'searchfoldername' was not declared in this scope
>
> 157    32  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'searchID' was not declared in this scope
>
> 165    33  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'averagedocsize' was not declared in this scope
>
> 173    29  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] could not convert 'isEmpty()' from 'void' to 'bool'
>
> 182    36  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'getRear' was not declared in this scope
>
> 193    45  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] 'getFront' was not declared in this scope
>
> C:\weblinky1.cpp  At global scope:
>
> 221    19  C:\weblinky1.cpp    [Error] variable or field 'enqueue' declared void

bellow is my complete code

```
    enter code here/**
 * Queue implementation using linked list in C.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CAPACITY 100    // Queue max capacity


/* Queue structure definition */
   struct documents 
{
     int id;
    char docname[50];
    char foldername[50];
    float docsize;
    struct document * next;
    struct document * previous;

};    



//Delacre document variable
struct documents Queue;

//Create node for linked list
struct node
{
    struct documents Queue;
    struct node* previous;
    struct node* next;
};

// Creating an empty linked list
struct node * rear = NULL;
struct node * front = NULL;


/* Queue size */
unsigned int size = 0;


void enqueue(Queue ** rear, Queue ** front, struct documents Queue);
void dequeue(Queue ** front);
void getRear(Queue * rear);
void getFront(Queue * front);
void isEmpty();
void isFull();


int main()
{
    int ch, data;
    Queue *rear, *front;
     struct documents Queue;
    int id;
    float docsize;
    char* docname;
    char* foldername;

    rear  = NULL;
    front = NULL;

    /* Run indefinitely until user manually terminates */
    while (1)
    {
        /* Queue menu */
        printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("  QUEUE LINKED LIST IMPLEMENTATION PROGRAM  \n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("1. Enqueue\n");
        printf("2. Dequeue\n");
        printf("3. Delete by Size of Document\n");
        printf("4. Display Documents based on Folder Name\n");
        printf("5. Enter ID to Display Index where Documents was 
          found\n");
        printf("6. Display Document Size Average\n");
        printf("7. Size of the Queue\n");
        printf("8. Get Rear\n");
        printf("9. Get Front\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Select an option: ");

        scanf("%d", &ch);


        /* Menu control switch */
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:

                 printf("\nEnter Document ID#: ");
                   scanf("%d", &Queue.id);
                    Queue.id = id;
                    printf("Enter Document size#: ");
                    scanf("%f", &Queue.docsize);
                     Queue.docsize = docsize;
                     printf("Enter Document name: ");
                      scanf("%s", &Queue.docname);
                       strcpy(Queue.docname, docname);
                       printf("Enter folder name: ");
                        scanf("%s", foldername);
                         strcpy(Queue.foldername, foldername);


                // Enqueue function returns 1 on success
                // otherwise 0
                if (enqueue(&rear, &front, Queue))
                    printf("Document added to queue.");
                else
                    printf("Queue is full.");

                break;

            case 2:
                Queue = dequeue(&front);

                // on success dequeue returns element removed

                if (Queue == NULL)
                    printf("Queue is empty.");
                else
                    printf("Queue => %d", Queue.front);

                break;

           //Delete by Size of Document
           case 3:

                 printf("Enter Document size: ");
                    scanf("%f", &docsize);
                    deletedocsize(docsize);

                break;

        //Display Documents based on Folder Name
        case 4:

                 printf("Enter Document Folder Name: ");
                     scanf("%s", foldername);
                    searchfoldername(foldername); 

                break;


        //Enter ID to Display Index where Documents was found
        case 5:

                 printf("Enter Document ID#: ");
                     scanf("%f", &id);
                    searchID(id); 

                break;


        //Display Document Size Average
        case 6:

                 averagedocsize(); 

                break;

            case 7: 

                // isEmpty() function returns 1 if queue is emtpy 
                // otherwise returns 0
                if (isEmpty())
                    printf("Queue is empty.");
                else 
                    printf("Queue size => %d", size);

                break;

            //get rear of document queue
            case 8: 
                data = getRear(rear);

                if (Queue == Queue.rear)
                    printf("Queue is empty.");
                else 
                    printf("Rear => %d", Queue.rear);

                break;

            case 9: 

                Queue = getFront(front);

                if (Queue == NULL)
                    printf("Queue is empty.");
                else 
                    printf("Front => %d", Queue.front);

                break;

            case 0:
                printf("Exiting from application.\n");
                exit(0);

            default:
                printf("Invalid choice, please input number between (0- 
       5).");
                break;
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }
}



/**
 * Enqueues/Insert an element at the rear of a queue.
 * Function returns 1 on success otherwise returns 0.
 */
void enqueue(Queue *q)
{
     Queue * temp= NULL;

    // Check queue out of capacity error
    if (isFull())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a new node of queue type
    temp = (Queue *) malloc (sizeof(Queue));

    // Assign data to new node
    temp->docs= en;

    // Initially new node does not point anything
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->previous = NULL;

    // Link new node with existing last node 
    if ( (*rear) )
    {
        (*rear)->next = temp;
    }


    // Make sure newly created node is at rear
    *rear = temp;

    // Link first node to front if its NULL
    if ( !( *front) )
    {
        *front = *rear;
    }

    // Increment quque size
    size++;

    return 1;
}


/**
 * Gets, element at rear of the queue. It returns the element
 * at rear of the queue on success otherwise return as 
 * error code.
 */
int getRear(Queue * rear)
{
    //  if queue is empty otherwise rear.
    return (isEmpty())
            ? NULL
            : rear->Queue.rear;
}


/**
 * Gets, element at front of the queue. It returns the element
 * at front of the queue on success otherwise return  as 
 * error code.
 */
int getFront(Queue * front)
{
    // if queue is empty otherwise front.
    return (isEmpty())
            ? NULL
            : front->Queue.front;
}


/**
 * Checks, if queue is empty or not.
 */
int isEmpty()
{
    return (size <= 0);
}


/**
 * Checks, if queue is within the maximum queue capacity.
 */
int isFull()
{
    return (size > CAPACITY);
}

// deleting any node based on position
void Delete(int n)
{
    struct documents temp1 =front;

      if(n == 1){
        front= temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
      }
      int i for(i =0; i<n-2; i++)
        temp1 = temp1->next;
      struct node* temp2 = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp2 -> next;
        free(temp2);
}

 //or using this method
void Dequeue(int n)
{
    struct documents temp1;

    if(Front == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
       int currentIndex = 0;
       struct documents *temp1 = (struct documents*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
        documents));
        bool traversing = true;


        tem1 = Front;
        temp1 = temp1->Queue;


        while(temp1 !=NULL) {
            if(temp1.id == n)
                {
                    temp1->previous->next=temp1->next;
                    free(temp1);
                printf("Item Deleted", currentIndex);
                return;
            }

            currentIndex++;

            temp1 = temp1->next;
            if (temp1 == NULL) {
                temp1 = temp1->previous;
            }
            temp1 = temp1->Queue;
        }
    }
}

//search by foldername
void searchfoldername(char foldername[])
{
    struct documents Queue;

    if(Front == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
    struct documents *tempp = (struct documents*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
     documents));
        bool traversing = true;
        int currIndex = 0;

        tempp = Front;
        tempy = tempp->Queue;
        Front = Front->next;

        while(traversing) {
            if(strcmp(tempy->foldername, foldername) == 0))
            {
                printf(" ID: %d\n", tempy->id);
                printf("Document Name: %s\n", tempy->docname);
                printf("Folder Name: %s\n", tempy->foldername);
                printf("Document Size: %d\n", tempy->docsize);
                printf("Document positioned at index: %d", currIndex);
                return tempy.foldername;
            }

            currIndex++;

            tempp = tempp->next;
            if (tempp == NULL) {
                tempp = tempp->previous;
            }
            tempy = tempp->Queue;
        }
    }
}

//delete document size
Void deletedocsize(int docsize)
{
    struct documents Queue;

    if(Front == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct documents *tempp = (struct documents*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
          documents));
     bool traversE = true;
        int currIndex = 0;

        tempp = Front;
        tempy = tempp->Queue;
        front = front->next;
            while(traversE) {
            if(strcmp(tempy->docsize, docsize) <= Queue.docsize))

            {
                free(tempp);
                    return;
            }

            currIndex++;
              tempp = tempp->next;
            if (tempp == NULL) {
                tempp = tempp->previous;
            }
            tempy = tempp->Queue;
        }
    }
}
};

//Enter ID to Display Index where Documents was found
void searchID(int id)
{
    struct documents Queue;

    if(Front == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct documents *tempp = (struct documents*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
         documents));
        bool traversing = true;
        int currIndex = 0;

        tempp = Front;
        tempy = tempp->Queue;
        Front = Front->next;

        while(traversing) {
            if(strcmp(tempy->id, id) == Queue.id))
            {
                printf("Document positioned at index: %d", currIndex);
                return tempy.id;
            }

            currIndex++;

            tempp = tempp->next;
            if (tempp == NULL) {
                tempp = tempp->previous;
            }
            tempy = tempp->Queue;
        }
    }
}

//find and display the Average of all document size
void averagedocsize()
{   
    struct documents Queue;

    if (front == NULL) 
    {
        printf("\n ooops List is Empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct documents *tempp = (struct documents*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
           documents));
        int count = 0;
        tempp = front;
        Queue = tempp->Queue;
        while (tempp != NULL) 
        {
            if(strcmp(Queue.docsize, docsize) == 0) {
                sum=0;
                while (count<=rearindex)
                {
                    sum = sum + docsize;
                    average =rearindex;
                }

                count++;
            }
            tempp = tempp->next;
            if (tempp == NULL) {
                printf("Average Document Size is : %d\n\n", average);
                break;
            }
            Queue = tempp->;
        }
        free(tempp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Queue` is _not_ declared as a type, so `Queue **` [or `Queue *`] is invalid. And, your `typedef` declares the `struct` name `Book` but _not_ a type of `Book` (i.e. it's legal but a bit malformed). Try: `typedef struct Book { what_you_already_have } Book;` Then, do `void Enqueue(Book **rear, Book **front, Book *en)`. When you did `struct Book Queue;`, `Queue` is merely a global instance of type `struct Book`--it does _not_ declare a _type_ of `Queue`.

Comment: When I compile this code I get a bunch of errors, but none of them is the error you say you got.  Please read and follow the [instructions for producing a minimal, complete, verifiable example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: While the code is certainly incorrect, it is hard to see how it would yield `[error] variable or field 'Enqueue' declared void` - it seems likely that this is not the code that generated the error.  Copy & paste your code and the errors carefully - do not remove content - for example the error message will include information such as the line number - don't remove that, and ensure the code you post includes that line.  Also your title bares no relation to the body text - the title is much broader (too broad), and the body very specific (about an error message).

Comment: From a style point of view, the name `Queue` is too generic to refer to specifically a queue of books, and the type is not a queue, but an element of a queue. `typedef Book* BookQueue ;` perhaps makes more sense, then the `Enqueue` parameters would have type `BookQueue*`.

Comment: thank you. I have updated the post to include my current code.

Comment: thank you. I have updated the post to include my current code.

Comment: In my opinion, if you're confused by the typedef (which seems to be the case given that the syntax is pretty mangled), just skip it.  Defining variables with "struct Queue A" is more clear than using a (mangled) typedef and defining variables with "Queue A".  Just don't use typedef's at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a *variable* `Queue` rather than a type, and the `typedef` is incomplete :

```
typedef struct Book
{
    int bID;
    char bName;
    char FolderName;
    struct Book * next
    struct Book * next
} Queue ;

void Enqueue(Queue ** rear, Queue ** front, Queue en) ;
```